# Cómo conseguir que salga el valor descrito en "if" en mi código de javascript

Tags: javascript, html, formularios

Quería saber cómo puedo conseguir que aparezca el valor de "else" cuando lanzo mi código. Debo hacer un validador de edad con javacript y formularios de HTML. Si en el formulario, la persona dice que tiene más de 18 años, se lanzará un mensaje que dirá "Vota". Si por el contrario el usuario introduce una edad menor a 18 años, saltará un mensaje que dirá "No votes". Mi problema es que siempre salta el mensaje de "No votes", es decir, el que aparece en el *else* aunque la edad sea más de 18 años.

Aqui mi código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">
function comprobar_edad()
    {
       var edad = document.getElementById('edad').value;
       if (edad >= 18) {
          alert("Vota");
       }

       else {
          alert("No votes");
       }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>VALIDADOR DE VOTANTES</h2>

<form name="myForm" id="edad" onsubmit="return comprobar_edad()" method="post">
  ¿Cuántos años tiene?:<br/><br/>
  <input type="text" name="fname"><br/><br/>
  ¿Está preparado para votar?:<br/><br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Compruébelo">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que el elemento cuyo *value* obtienes es 'edad', y se trata del form. Cuando intentas obtener el *value* de 'edad' obtienes un resultado que hace que se cumpla el **else** de la instrucción. La solución es poner un atributo 'id' al elemento input que coincida con el que empleas en

```
var edad = document.getElementById('edad').value;
```

Por ejemplo:

```
var edad = document.getElementById('inputedad').value;
```

En ese caso la variable 'edad' contendrá el *value* del elemento 'inputedad' y te funcionará.

El código quedaría así:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function comprobar_edad() {
            var edad = document.getElementById('inputedad').value;
            if (edad >= 18) {
                alert("Vota");
            }

            else {
                alert("No votes");
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>VALIDADOR DE VOTANTES</h2>

<form name="myForm" id="edad" onsubmit="return comprobar_edad()" method="post">
        ¿Cuántos años tiene?:<br /><br />
        <input type="text" id="inputedad"><br /><br />
        ¿Está preparado para votar?:<br /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Compruébelo">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```